# How to use variables in kivy, that are defined in another .py module (not main.py)?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to have all the variables for an app defined in a .py module separate from the main.py file. Then I want to use those variables inside a kivy file.

I have tried the code below with several variations and there are always errors. The module works fine for defining for example different Fonts but, when it comes to properties(ObjectProperty) it does not work.

**Project structure:**

- KivyFolder

  - modules(folder)

    - variables.py
  - screens(folder)

    - screen1.kv
    - screen2.kv
  - main.py
  - main.kv

**Code:**

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from os import listdir
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv_screens = './screens/'
for kv in listdir(kv_screens):
    Builder.load_file(kv_screens+kv)

class Screen1(Screen):
    pass

class Screen2(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file('main.kv')

class MainApp(App):

    import modules.variables

    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.1

ScreenManagement:
    Screen1:
    Screen2:
```

screen1.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.1

<Screen1>:
    name: 's1'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Screen 1'
            font_size: app.font_size_one
        Button:
            text: 'Go To Screen 2'
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = 's2'
```

screen2.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.1

<Screen2>:
    name: 's2'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Screen 2'
            font_size: '20dp'
        Button:
            text: 'Go To Screen 1'
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = 's1'
```

variables.py

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

font_size_one = ObjectProperty('40dp')
font_size_two = ObjectProperty('60dp')
```

Now doing it like this produces this error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'

I would expect to be able to call a variable since it is imported at MainApp(App), so 'app.variable name should read it.

I have also tried:

```
font_size: app.variables.font_size_one
```

and:

```
font_size: app.modules.variables.font_size_one
```

Then I tried importing the module before everything else with the same result.

I also tried putting it into a class and calling that class in .kv like this:

variables.py

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class FVArs():
    font_size_one = ObjectProperty('40dp')
    font_size_two = ObjectProperty('60dp')
```

screen1.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.1

<Screen2>:
    name: 's2'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Screen 2'
            font_size: FVars().font_size_two
        Button:
            text: 'Go To Screen 1'
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = 's1'
```

Error:

NameError: name 'FVars' is not defined

Thank you for your answers.

Bye

**EDIT: Since the answer below works on the example code but not in my actual project I am adding the relevant project code:**

**Project structure:**

- KivyFolder

  - modules(folder)

    - global_variables.py
  - screens(folder)

    - Intro.kv
    - (and other screens as separate .kv files
  - main.py
  - main.kv

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App

from modules.global_variables import globalVariables

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty, ObjectProperty, Property

from kivy.core.window import Window          

background_color = (0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1)        
Window.clearcolor = background_color         

from os import listdir                       
from kivy.lang import Builder   

kv_screens = './screens/'                       
for kv in listdir(kv_screens):                  
    Builder.load_file(kv_screens+kv)            
kv_elements = './elements/'                      
for kv in listdir(kv_elements):                  
    Builder.load_file(kv_elements+kv)       

class IntroScreen(Screen): 
    user_name = StringProperty("Troll")   

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass        

presentation = Builder.load_file("main.kv") 

class MainApp(App):

    title_size = globalVariables.title_size

    def build(self):                         
        self.title = 'Kivy Omnia!'           
        return presentation                   


if __name__ == "__main__":                   
    app = MainApp()                          
    app.run()
```

global_variables.py

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class globalVariables():

    title_size = ObjectProperty('101sp')
```

main.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.1

ScreenManagement:
    IntroScreen:
```

intro.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.1


<IntroScreen>:
    name: "intro"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: "Hello " +  root.user_name + "!"
            font_size: app.title_size
```

**Error:**

> kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File
>   "C:\Users\Ghost\CodeProjects\phyton\kivyomnia\screens\Intro.kv", line
>   10:  ...
>          8:        Label:
>          9:            text: "Hello " +  root.user_name + "!"
>
> > > 10:            font_size: app.title_size
> > >             11:            font_name: "Exo-B"
> > >             12:        AnchorLayout:  ...  BuilderException: Parser: File "C:\Users\Ghost\CodeProjects\phyton\kivyomnia\screens\Intro.kv", line
> > >       10:  ...
> > >              8:        Label:
> > >              9:            text: "Hello " +  root.user_name + "!"
> > >         10:            font_size: app.title_size
> > >             11:            font_name: "Exo-B"
> > >             12:        AnchorLayout:  ...  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'    File
> > >       "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 249, in
> > >       create_handler
> > >            return eval(value, idmap), bound_list    File "C:\Users\Ghost\CodeProjects\phyton\kivyomnia\screens\Intro.kv", line
> > >       10, in 
> > >            font_size: app.title_size    File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 75, in
> > >       **getattribute**
> > >            object.**getattribute**(self, '_ensure_app')()    File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 70, in
> > >       _ensure_app
> > >            app.bind(on_stop=lambda instance:
>
> File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line
>   615, in _apply_rule
>        rctx['ids'])    File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 254, in
>   create_handler
>        cause=tb)

So if just reposition the:

```
title_size = globalVariables.title_size
```

... inside the IntroScreen(Screen) and then inside Intro.kv:

```
font_size: root.title_size
```

... it works. But the point is to have all the global variables available across all screens.

Another question:

if app.something gets a what is inside main app class 
and root.something gets what is in the root class of that file then how do you call something from another class that is not app or root. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import your `FVars` class with this line:

```
from modules.variables import FVars
```

Then inside your `MainApp` class, you can create a class variable with the data of `FVars`'s class variable.

```
class MainApp(App):
    f1 = FVars.font_size_one
```

You can then access it on your kv files:

```
font_size: app.f1
```

Here is some basic example:

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

from modules.variables import FVars

class Test(App):
    f1 = FVars.font_size_one

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("test.kv")

Test().run()
```

test.kv

```
BoxLayout:
    Label:
        text: "Hello"
        font_size: app.f1
```

modules/variables.py

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class FVars():
    font_size_one = ObjectProperty('40dp')
    font_size_two = ObjectProperty('60dp')
```

**UPDATE**

To prevent the error, you can load the kv files inside the `build` method.

```
def build(self):                         
    self.title = 'Kivy Omnia!'           

    kv_screens = './screens/'                       
    for kv in listdir(kv_screens):                  
        Builder.load_file(kv_screens+kv)            

    kv_elements = './elements/'                      
    for kv in listdir(kv_elements):                  
        Builder.load_file(kv_elements+kv)  

    presentation = Builder.load_file("main.kv") 

    return presentation
```

There's a plenty of ways on how to access a variable inside a class which is neither an `app` nor `root`, you can just set the `id` property of that widget.

Here's a basic example:

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class SecondClass(BoxLayout):
    someNumber = 123 # Let's say we wanted to print the value of this variable when we press the button.

class FirstClass(BoxLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return FirstClass()


TestApp().run()
```

test.kv

```
<SecondClass>:

<FirstClass>:

    Button: 
        text: "Print the Numbah"
        on_press: print(app.root.ids.secondclass.someNumber) # We can do something like this
    SecondClass:
        id: secondclass
```

We can also do something like this:

```
<SecondClass>:

<FirstClass>:

    Button: 
        text: "Print the Numbah"
        on_press: print(root.ids.secondclass.someNumber) 
    SecondClass:
        id: secondclass
```

Or this:

```
<SecondClass>:

<FirstClass>:

    Button: 
        text: "Print the Numbah"
        on_press: print(secondclass.someNumber)
    SecondClass:
        id: secondclass
```

Or even this:

```
<SecondClass>:

<FirstClass>:
    second: secondclass
    Button:
        text: "Print the Numbah"
        on_press: print(app.root.second.someNumber)

    SecondClass:
        id: secondclass
```

And this:

```
<SecondClass>:

<FirstClass>:
    second: secondclass
    Button:
        text: "Print the Numbah"
        on_press: print(root.second.someNumber)
    SecondClass:
        id: secondclass
```

Comment: from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty is underlined, saying 'no name 'ObjectProperty' in module 'kivy.properties'. This stays there even if the variables work.

Comment: Also in my own code it still bugs me about Attribute error although I written it exactly like in your example, while newly written code that you provided works. How is that even a thing?

Comment: Can you post the error you got? with your updated code?

Comment: ok I'll edit the original question later and add the whole code. It is working if I put the variable inside a class and call it with root.something, just not if it is in the MainApp (App) class and called with app.something...

Comment: Thank you. I can't upvote the answer since I don't have enough reputation but you just explained a lot.